# java.util.Map implementation with generics

Tags: java, generics

I want to create an implementation of java.util.Map which only takes String as key and value.

I tried several things

```
abstract class BaseMap<String,String> implements Map<K,V>
```

this gives a compile error mebe because I am implementing the interface and not fulfilling the full definition of Key and Value

then I tried extending the interface to define types, it does nt let me do that as well

```
public interface IBaseMap<String, String> extends Map<K, V>
```

It still gives error "The type parameter String is hiding java.lang.String"

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: `implements Map<String, String>`

Comment: abstract class BaseMap<String, String> implements Map<String,String> this gives an error too. Now, if I remove the Generics from class name it works, but then dont I loose the type enforcement from Generics?

Comment: Valid is either `BaseMap implements Map<String,String>` or `BaseMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>`...

Comment: No, since the enforcement is coming from the specified types you are implementing. You are nailing the implementation of `Map` to `String`, so your `BaseMap` cannot overcome that (thus is nailed down to `String`, too)

Comment: @ppeterka66 That would allow any types which is not what he wants.

Comment: @IngoBürk can u post it as an answer, so that I can accept your answer

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the other answers. They might have been after me, but they are more precise and explanatory. I suggest anubhava's answer since he answers your question most precisely (imho).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide concrete types while extending an Interface of generics like:

```
abstract class StringToStringMap implements Map<String, String> {
   // ...
}
```

Or if you want to extend `Map<K, v>` interface then:

```
interface IBaseMap extends Map<String, String> {
   // ...       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need inheritance here? You should really avoid using it like this. You can work with composition in better way:

```
class CustomMap<K extends String, V extends String> {
    private Map<K, V> map;

    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now, you can instantiate your `CustomMap` with only `String` as type argument, which eventually is used as key and value for enclosed `Map`.

---

In fact, no need to make the class generic at all, as specified by @TedHopp in comments. Just enclose a `Map<String, String>`:

```
class CustomMap {
    private Map<String, String> map;
}
```

Comment: Since `String` is `final`, there's no need for `K extends String`, etc.

Comment: @TedHopp. Yeah. But that is necessary to specify bounds for type parameters

Comment: I see no need for type parameters at all. Just declare `private Map<String, String> map;` and `public Map<String, String> getMap() . . .`

Comment: @TedHopp. I guess that is necessary for enforcing type parameters for `Map`.

Comment: @TedHopp. OOPs. Totally missed that.